# iptables - why do I get "Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)"

Tags: kernel, iptables, firewall

I need to install some iptable ruels to block traffic that originates from a certain country, I found this script example on http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/block-entier-country-using-iptables/ it works great on another host I have but on this one (an embedded box) I get:

```
./iptable_rules.sh 
modprobe: module ip_tables not found in modules.dep
iptables v1.4.16.3: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Now upgrading the kernel due to the nature of the device, is not an option. Does anyone know a way I can get around this? This system running on kernel `3.2.34`

Comment: Are you running the script (and thus iptables itself) as root or as a normal user? It will complain about many similar things if you are not running it as root.

Comment: @bytor I'm running it as root, must be something else...

Comment: Do you have the kernel configuration? If so you can compile and load the requisite module (assuming module loading hasn't been disabled).

Comment: try `lsmod | grep ip` , what do you get ?

Comment: @neuron I get nothing: `# lsmod |grep ip \n# `, I have to see if I can dig the kernel configuration up, it's a `busybox` distribution I built way back when using `Buildroot`

Comment: `modprobe ip_tables;
    modprobe ip_conntrack;
   modprobe iptable_filter;
    modprobe ipt_state`. If the modules are not loaded after this then you will have to do as @Gilles said

Comment: @neuron naw, nothing is included, this is very bare bone system...`# modprobe ip_tables; modprobe ip_conntrack; modprobe iptable_filter;\n modprobe ipt_state\n
modprobe: module ip_tables not found in modules.dep\n
modprobe: module ip_conntrack not found in modules.dep\n
modprobe: module iptable_filter not found in modules.dep\n
modprobe: module ipt_state not found in modules.dep\n
# `

Comment: It looks like iptables simply isn't available on your embedded device.

Comment: Try following this [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4815)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to re-compile it using something to the similar commands.

```
make KERNEL_DIR=/usr/src/linux
make install KERNEL_DIR=/usr/src/linux

make dep
make bzImage
make
make install
make modules
```

Source: [iptables: Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/iptables-table-does-not-exist-do-you-need-to-insmod.3196/)